# angular - showing alert when user leaves one page (one component)

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-router, angular-router-guards

**Expected behavior**

I have one page which contains one form, when the user want to leave this page, actually it is just one component, I want show some alert like "Do you really want to leave this page? Your changes will not be saved".

**Currently behavior**

I have tried

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) yourfunction($event) {
  return $event.returnValue='Your changes will not be saved';
}
```

But the dialogue didn't appear.

Any ideas or suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in Angular the transition between pages is not a "real" one, and the window.beforeunload event does not fire. To manage this, you have to use Angular's own Router Guards, specifically a `canDeactivate` one. Here is a [link](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) to the specific doc about the `canDeactivate` guard. Your actual code may look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<YourComponent> {
    canDeactivate(){
//your popup logic goes here. Note that this method should return 
// a boolean, or a Promise/Observable of a boolean, if any async operations are present
   }
}
```

After you create this guard, you just have to place it on your route definition:

```
{path: 'path-to-your-component', component: YourComponent, canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuard]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use canDeactivate as i used in my application
below example

```
     @Injectable()
export class RouteLinkGuard implements CanDeactivate<Componentchanged> {
  constructor(private router: Router, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private commonService: CommonService) {}

  canDeactivate(Componentchanged: Componentchanged) {
// Here you can use whatever logic you want 
    if (this.commonService.getChangedValue() === true) {
      return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Are you sure you want to leave this page? Any unsaved data would be lost?',
          header: 'Not saved',
          icon: 'fa fa-info',
          accept: () => {
            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
          },
          reject: () => {
            observer.next(false);
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

//In Module
// You is like below
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Componentchanged,
    canDeactivate: [RouteLinkGuard]
  }
];
```